# JavaScript DOM not getting pre assigned CSS properties

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am setting the background size value of an object in CSS as `background-size: cover;`, but when I change the image with JavaScript the new background takes the default property. Is this normal?

Thank you.

Edit: I have solved the problem by reassigning the value in JavaScript, but I am still curious as to why it does not work.

Comment: May you share a runnable [mcve] in the question? At the moment we can't replicate your issue.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I'm guessing that you are changing the image using the CSS Property `background`, rather than `background-image`, are you? If you are, know that the former is a shorthand for multiple properties.

Comment: Thank you, I have had this same problem in multiple projects, but this worked!